# How to define additional 'OutputForm' formats?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, output

I would like to define an additional `OutputForm` command such that, when applied to a long expression involving several variables (probably at different levels, within nested arrays and functions), it replaces all the variables with their corresponding formats. In this way, I'd like to be able to display `SomeExpression` in two different ways, using

```
SomeExpression //OutputForm
SomeExpression //OutputForm2
```

As for the format definition, for each variable, I'd like to be able to specify it via:

```
Format[SomeVariable,"OutputForm2"]:=SomeFormattingInstructions
```

In addition, it would be desirable to set `OutputForm` as the default function for variables that lack a pre-defined `OutputForm2` format.

P.S. Note that [Similar questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51179/user-defined-output-forms) have been asked before, but no solutions have been given without overwriting the default OutputForm/StandardForm/etc functions.

Comment: Slightly difficult to work without examples, but would this work? `Clear[OutputForm2];

OutputForm2[expr_] := Block[{OutputForm},
  Format[f[x_], OutputForm] := f^x;
  OutputForm[expr]
  ]; OutputForm2[f[x] + f[y] + 1]`

Comment: Thanks @Domen. However, please note that although you added {OutputForm} to Block[], this is still rewriting the OutputForm of f[x]. To check this, write: `OutputForm[f[x]+f[y]+1]`, then `OutputForm2[f[x]+f[y]+1]`, and then again `OutputForm[f[x]+f[y]+1]`. It might be because OutputForm is `Protected`?. 
Perhaps we should so something like this instead: `OutputForm2[expr_]:=Block[{OutputForm},Format[f[x_],OutputForm]:=f^x; Return[OutputForm[expr]]; "..." ];` where "..." stands for some code to undo the initial Format[f[x_],OutputForm] call.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I see ... Hm. The only silly solution that comes to my mind now is to make `OutputForm3` behave as a regular `OutputForm` by removing all `FormatValues`: ```OutputForm2[expr_] := Module[{},  Format[f[x_], OutputForm] := f^x;  OutputForm[expr]   ];
OutputForm3[expr_] := Module[{}, FormatValues[f] := {}; OutputForm[expr]
   ];```